# pytest assert_called_with doesn't work with Django management commands

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

**Django management command:** `my_custom_command.py`

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from services.external import ExternalApi


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        api = ExternalApi()
        api.my_custom_method("param")
```

**Test Code:**

```
from django.core.management import call_command

from myapp.management.commands import my_custom_command


def test_custom_command(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(my_custom_command, 'ExternalApi')
    call_command('my_custom_command')
    my_custom_command.ExternalApi.my_custom_method.assert_called_with('param')
```

**Result:**

```
    def test_custom_command(mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(my_custom_command, 'ExternalApi')
        call_command('my_custom_command')
>       my_custom_command.ExternalApi.my_custom_method.assert_called_with('param')
E       AssertionError: Expected call: my_custom_method('param')
E       Not called
```

Though the my_custom_method has been invoked, the test couldn't find the method call. It seems to be the context is missing. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asserting the class itself, not the class instances. Example:

```
api_cls_mock = mocker.patch.object(my_custom_command, 'ExternalApi')
# this line will get the method mock of ExternalApi's instances:
meth_mock = api_mock.return_value.my_custom_method
call_command('my_custom_command')
# method mock will track the calls
meth_mock.assert_called_with('param')
```